# Save the mysql queries(Insert, Delete, Update) to database in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I want to log/save all the mysql queries(insert ,delete,update) and there duration respectively in a log table.
Please let me know how this can be done in cakephp 3

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging